# Is there a good way of doing a replacement for canNotActivate in routing in Angular?

Tags: angular

Say I have an AuthGuard in Angular 2 that checks whether I am logged in or not. If I am not logged in I get redirected to /login. The redirect logic is in the AuthGuard.

```
path: '',
component: HomeComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
```

But what if I am already logged in, and try to go to /login page. How is the best way of redirecting to the home page if a user is already logged in and tries to access /login page? There is no canNotActivate on the router. Should I make two AuthGuards? One that is called AuthGuardNegate or something?

Is there good approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way to do it is to use an AuthGuard for pages which need to be authenticated and an UnauthGuard for the ones you want only to show when not logged in; just like you said.
Might not be the best way but that works nicely :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class UnauthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

    canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['/app']); //Path to your authenticated-only page
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in your routing module :

```
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPage,
    canActivate: [
        UnauthGuard
    ]
},
```